# Is there a way of selecting an element at a certain position of a nodelist?

Tags: css

I am trying to select an element using CSS but the closest I can get is a nodelist using `document.querySelectorAll()` in the developer console.  Is there a way of selecting a specific position in the nodelist like you can a standard array e.g. nodelist[3]?

Comment: You just want 1 element? then use `document.querySelector()` it will return just the element you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that but it wasn't specific enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to select a sibling element by index (one-based). For example, if you had something like `div > ul > li:nth-child(3)`, it would retrieve the third `<li>` element available per that selector.

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much. Perfect

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was:

document.querySelector('div.donation-details-area ul.details-list li:nth-child(1) span.value').textContent

and using a GTM DOM element all I had to do was:
div.donation-details-area ul.details-list li:nth-child(1) span.value